# display newly created pdf to another tab

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Here's what I'm trying to do. When i click hyperlink it should open a new tab then display my newly created pdf. But my code keeps on displaying it at current tab.

code for view

```
@Html.ActionLink("User", "PRintPDF", new { target = "_blank" })
```

and for controller

```
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-length", renderedBytes.Length.ToString());
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=somefile.pdf");
    Response.BinaryWrite(renderedBytes); 
    Response.Flush();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11100981/asp-net-mvc-open-pdf-file-in-new-window

Comment: This should work in most browsers. What OS and browser are you using?

Comment: That's what i thought. I'm using FF version 39.0 and windows 7 for my OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this on your view

```
@Html.ActionLink("User", "PRintPDF", new {id = 1}, new {@target="_blank"})
```

actionlink should have 4 parameters for html attributes.